# Entity Framework and OFFSET/FETCH on Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I just encountered a weird bug in my app where a paged data grid contained duplicate rows.

Investigation showed that it's because the new paging mechanism Entity Framework uses with Sql Server 2012 as of version 6.1.2 *only works on strictly ordered column sets*, as [is documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx#Anchor_5).

Since most columns are not strictly ordered (meaning you have duplicate entries with respect to the sort order), simply binding one of the typical grid middlewares to Entity Framework is now broken subtly and horribly.

I can't believe I'm the first to complain, but I did google!

I [found at least a dba.stackexchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138206/offset-fetch-overlapping-results-on-second-page) of a fellow wondering why Sql Server behaves this way.

Like the cynical old man I am, I already anticipated with a grin on my face what the fellow got as an answer: It's by design, what do you think?

Since I have little control over how middlewares create their linq, the only hope left is that Entity Framework has provided a way to fall back to the previous implementation of paging by using the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...` feature, which always worked splendidly.

Is there? Any other ideas?

**EDIT:**

Here's an example of how a not strictly ordered column set leads to duplicates. (The linked question also has examples on SQL Fiddle but they don't seem to work right now.)

```
create table Foo(
  name varchar(10) not null primary key,
  value varchar(10) not null
  );

insert into Foo values ('1', ''), ('2', ''), ('3', ''), ('4', '')

select * from Foo order by value offset 0 rows fetch next 2 rows only;
select * from Foo order by value offset 2 rows fetch next 2 rows only;
```

This gives for me:

```
name    value
3   
2   

name    value
2   
1
```

As you can see, they overlap. The reason is that the value column itself is always empty and thus not strictly ordered.

The previous way Entity Framework implemented paging used a the ROW_NUMBER feature like this:

```
select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by value) as rownumber, * from Foo) as squery where squery.rownumber between 1 and 2;
select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by value) as rownumber, * from Foo) as squery where squery.rownumber between 3 and 4;
```

These queries indeed give disjoint results.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected vs current results

Comment: It's not merely by design, it's functionally impossible for SQL Server to guarantee consistent results unless you run them over uniquely ordered results. It can't "magic up" a unique value for every `ORDER BY` that will remain consistent across executions (or rather, it could, but this would be horrendously expensive). To fix this, add the primary key(s) of your data set to the `ORDER BY` so the result *is* totally ordered (or rather, EF should do so...). Note that `ROW_NUMBER()` has the exact same potential problem, but due to the vagaries of implementation you could get lucky more often.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's obviously not true, otherwise the ROW_NUMBER approach wouldn't work either (see the added sample). I'm also pretty sure that MySQL's limit/offset feature worked on not-totally-ordered row sets properly as well, and has so for ages.

Comment: Yes, it is my assertion that the `ROW_NUMBER` approach can also give back inconsistent results between executions. Unfortunately, proving that this is so is not at all easy, because by default you can indeed expect the optimizer to always pick the same execution plan in terms of index scans and parallelism, so this almost always works. It is, as they say, good enough. I certainly don't expect you to take me on my word, though. (And what MySQL does is neither here nor there, I'm afraid. It may well be possible for MySQL's execution engine, I don't know the internals of *that*.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's a disturbing assertion. Is a different query plan the only case when that could happen? I'm reasonably confident that at least different query plans for the query should be extremely rare as I don't think the query planner gets to see the numbers behind OFFSET and FETCH NEXT if they are properly parameterized - so it should used a cached plan. Are there other cases where you think it could happen?

Comment: To be clear, I don't know how `OFFSET`/`FETCH NEXT` is implemented -- obviously differently from a straightforward `ROW_NUMBER` and likely "optimized", which is why it "fails" more often in the case of non-uniqueness. I do know how `ROW_NUMBER()` and `ORDER BY` work, and that's why I know the results could vary -- if the `ORDER BY` is not unique, and the plan is parallel, then it's up to runtime considerations which processor processes which page, and hence the final order *can* vary between executions even with an identical plan. It's just that *in practice*, this tends not to occur often.

Comment: What's the middleware that's generating the linq query?  Perhaps you need to focus on finding a way to "fix" it instead.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sounds plausible. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: @wdosanjos You're probably right. I use DevExtreme.AspNet.Data, the .NET server-side data lib of the DevExtreme Javascript toolkit. I think I already found a way to get this to work without hacking the lib itself.